# Bulk download from USGS The National Map (TNM)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, conda

I am looking for a way to bulk download data from the USGS The National Map (TNM).  I found approximately 150 small (10MB) DEM tiles.  The official USGS instructions are to download an open source software called uGET ([TNM bulk download instructions](https://apps.nationalmap.gov/uget-instructions/index.html)), feed it a .txt file containing all the information for those aforementioned 150 tiles (created easily in TNM), and batch download the files.  However, the software (uGET) is buggy and constantly frozen.  I have the URLs to the DEM tiles I selected in this format via the txt file:

> `https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/CA_West_Coast_LiDAR_2016_B16/CA_WestCoastElNinoUTM11_2016/TIFF/<filename>.tif`

According to the instructions from NJ GIS Network, I should be able to bulk download from AWS in a similar CL call `aws s3 cp s3:PATH/TO/DEMs c:\DEM\ --no-sign-request --recursive`.

Is anybody familiar with `aws` bulk downloading in general, or specifically to the TNF?  My problem appears to be the `PATH/TO/DEMs` argument.  Note that I passed as above `https://prd...s3...CA_WestCoast...` without `<filename>`.

Comment: Downloading data through http is a simple and well known task. Are you sure that uGET is buggy, or could it be that something in the background service makes download to fail? How many simultaneous downloads do you run?

Comment: Hi @user30184 - yeah I can't even run it.  I got it to work once.  Had to open and close it like 30 times.  It just stalls.  There were some posts on reddit and on other GIS forums indicating similar behavior.

Comment: I installed uGET and  as a test downloaded a few gigabytes of imagery from another site that I know. I had no problems but that is off-topic and does not help you to download data from the USGS site.

Comment: Terrible at formatting code in responses, so apologies.  But uGET issue could be my machine.  Anyways, I found a way to do it with the Windows Powershell.  Note that `data_in` and `data_out` are columns in the csv from `$csv_data` which hold the URL to the tiff and full/path/to/file_out.tif respectively.  Here are the two lines for Powershell:  FIRST LINE  ```>>>$csv_data = Import-Csv path/to/file.csv``` SECOND LINE 
```>>>foreach($row in $csv_data){Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $row.data_in -OutFile $row.data_out```